# OS X: USB drive with FAT partition not mounting

Tags: macos, hard-drive, usb, mount

I have an external USB 2.0 drive with a single FAT partition.

My OS X 10.8.5 computer is not mounting it, even if the same computer originally formatted the disk and copied the files onto it. This disk has never been used attached to a computer different from this one.

The drive is seen by Disk Utility.

What can the reason be?

Comment: try and see if you can read it in a windows pc? or vm? maybe its corrupted

Comment: I am running Verify/Repair disk, but it takes quite a bit.

Comment: The disk cannot even be repaired: I have just realised of having lost GBs of data. Nice to know that a 1 year old HD can get corrupted even spending its days laying horizontally on a flat desk.

Comment: hdd failures not only happen by moving it, there are more factors in play, sometimes just random - also depending on environment temperature etc... you can try repairing with a linux distro and may recover pictures etc with Photorec: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec